# Can I test OpenID Provider on server from a Relying Party in my local machine? - DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: asp.net, .net, openid, dotnetopenauth

I had created a provider and a Relying Party in Visual Studio using the DNOA library and it worked well. Then, I moved the provider to the server and tried to test it from the Relying Party from my local machine. The RP gives the error of 'No OpenID endpoint found'.

I think I am missing something in Web.config. In the `WhitelistHost` attribute, I have added the wildcard "*" which should make the provider to accept requrests from anyone (for testing purpose). Is there anything else that I am not aware of? I am relatively new to the topic.

Web.config -

```
<!-- The uri section is necessary to turn on .NET 3.5 support for IDN (international domain names),
   which is necessary for OpenID urls with unicode characters in the domain/host name. 
   It is also required to put the Uri class into RFC 3986 escaping mode, which OpenID and OAuth require. -->
<uri>
    <idn enabled="All"/>
    <iriParsing enabled="true"/>
</uri>
```

```
<!-- this is an optional configuration section where aspects of DotNetOpenAuth can be customized -->
<dotNetOpenAuth>
    <openid>
        <provider>
            <security requireSsl="false" />
            <behaviors>
                <!-- Behaviors activate themselves automatically for individual matching requests. 
           The first one in this list to match an incoming request "owns" the request.  If no
           profile matches, the default behavior is assumed. -->
                <!--<add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Provider.Behaviors.PpidGeneration, DotNetOpenAuth"/>-->
            </behaviors>
        </provider>
    </openid>
    <messaging>
        <untrustedWebRequest>
            <whitelistHosts>
                <!-- since this is a sample, and will often be used with localhost -->
                <add name="localhost"/>
                <add name="*"/>
            </whitelistHosts>
        </untrustedWebRequest>
    </messaging>
    <!-- Allow DotNetOpenAuth to publish usage statistics to library authors to improve the library. -->
    <reporting enabled="true" />
</dotNetOpenAuth>

<appSettings>
    <add key="whitelistedRealms" value="http://localhost:39165/;http://othertrustedrealm/;http://localhost/;http://localhost:4856/"/>
    <!-- Set ImplicitAuth to true when using Windows auth, or false for FormsAuthentication -->
    <add key="ImplicitAuth" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
....
```

**Edit:** I am not sure if it matters but the server uses SSL.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you ever found an answer to this question, but I had the same problem. I was able to repair the issue but Whitelisting localhost on not only the Provider end but also the Relying Part end as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try being explicit in your whitelisthosts configuration - put the address of your server in.

Short of this, [turn on logging](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/wiki/Logging-and-debugging#option-2---logging-directly-with-log4net) on both the RP and the ID server. Step through the process on the RP.

Also, do you have a proxy between your dev PC and the internet ? if so you will need to tell your RP code how to communicate through it.